# proto3 message type for json marshal data

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc-go, proto3

I am implementing a gRPC API and wanted to add JSON body data as it is in response.

so I have tried:

```
type Message struct {
    Subject string `json:"subject"`
    Body    interface{}  `json:"body"`
}
```

proto3

```
message Message {
    string subject = 1;
    string body = 2;
}
```

API code:

```
    en, err := client.Request.Get(req.Name)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, status.Error(codes.InvalidArgument, err.Error())
    }

    data, _ := json.Marshal(en.Body)

    return &response.Message{
        Subject: en.Subject,
        Body:    string(data),
    }, nil
```

After adding this getting gRPC API response:

```
{
  "subject": "dev",
  "body": "{\"name\":\"environment\",\"description\":\"The default environment\"}",
}
```

The problem is body JSON key-value is dynamic.
Is there any way by which we can get response something like

```
{
  "subject": "dev",
  "body": {"name":"environment","description":"The default environment"},
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:
go to the go playground (https://play.golang.org/)
and then put this in:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "strconv"
)


func main() {

    b := []byte(`"{\"name\":\"environment\",\"description\":\"The default environment\"}"`)
    fmt.Println(string(b))


    var msg string
        json.Unmarshal([]byte(b), &msg)

    smsg, _ := strconv.Unquote(string(b))

    fmt.Println(smsg)


}
```

what we're doing is unmarshalling the marshalled response and then using strconv unquote to get the string we want

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to embed a truly arbitrary object into the payload like this with protocol buffers, if you want the default proto-to-JSON conversion.

You could inject your own logic to do the conversion to JSON and have it do what you're expecting.

Depending on what your broader goal is, [Any](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any)s might also be useful.

---

Note that the `json` tags here:

```golang
type Message struct {
    Subject string `json:"subject"`
    Body    interface{}  `json:"body"`
}
```

are not relevant. gRPC is generating the JSON based on the *protocol buffer* type `Message`; the tags here only affect how the Go json library will render the *Go* type `Message`.